# How to convert a byte to sbyte

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, byte

The situation:

- Person A is sending a single byte assuring that it represents a sbyte.
- Person B trusts person A, and has to interpret the received byte as a sbyte variable.

Example:

- Person A sends: 1000 0000 (-128 in 2 complement)
- Person B receives it and has to interpret it into a sbyte variable

In C# I did:

```cs
sbyte mysbyte = unchecked((sbyte)receivedByte); //receivedByte's type is byte
```

Since I put the `unchecked` keyword, instead of throwing an overflow exception, I get `-128`.

How can I do the same in VB.Net without changing compiler's options? The unchecked keyword doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: `CSByte(If(receivedByte < 128, receivedByte, receivedByte - 256))`

Comment: Is it a single byte only, or it is an array of Byte?

Comment: @Ian Single byte only. Plutonix's solution solved the issue.